# Solving initial value problem using Laplace transforms, one other method, and comparing results

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

[image]

So for my solution using characteristic equations I get (fixed a typo for first coefficient) $$\frac{11}{30} e^{-3t} - \frac{21}{20} e^{-2t} + \frac{21}{20} e^{2t} - \frac{11}{30} e^{3t}$$ For the solution using the Laplace Transform I end up in a very different place, with $$ \frac{2s^2 -29 - \frac{36}{s^2}} {s^4 - 13s^2}$$ The partial fraction of this does not appear to lead me to the same answer as above. To me this seems like there's a mistake, but I can't find one and the question does ask for me to compare results. Is it okay for the results to differ?

Comment: May be a typo somewhere. I got $$\frac{11 }{30}e^{-3 t}-\frac{21 }{20}e^{-2 t}+\frac{21 }{20}e^{2 t}-\frac{11}{30} e^{3
   t}$$ which is almost identical to your answer (except the first coefficient).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I made a typo in my post for the first coefficient. I got that too using characteristic equations. For the Laplace transform, I've checked my work quite a bit and I'm just not spotting the mistake. [Here is my work](http://i.imgur.com/9uXSXQf.png)

Comment: Sorry but I really don't know anything in the area of Laplace transforms (just as in many, many, many other areas !).

Comment: You need to show your work before we can identify the problem. Specifically, what did you do for the Laplace?